# Flutter how to get current duration time in assets_audio_player

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, audio-player, just-audio

I am previously using just_audio and I am taking the current time like this

```
player.positionStream.listen((event) {
  playerTimeNow = event;
  updatePlayerBar();
});
```

Now I need to know how can I get time in this [assets_audio_player](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player)

Comment: Did you mean audio_service? It comes with a complete example for just_audio that can be downloaded and run, so that might help. If your app has different requirements from that example, perhaps you could go into more detail in your question about the points where that example is inadequate and I'll try to write up an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I understood from your question is that you want the current playing position of the audio and want to update your player bar. For that you can use `currentPosition` property of `AssetAudioPlayer` which returns `ValueStream`. Yon can either `listen` to the `currentPosition` `Stream` or use it in `StreamBuilder`.

**Simply `listen` to the `currentPosition` Stream :**

```
 assetsAudioPlayer.currentPosition.listen((positionValue){
   playerTimeNow = positionValue;
  updatePlayerBar();
 });
```

Or you can also use `StreamBuilder`:

```
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: assetsAudioPlayer.currentPosition,
    builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
        final Duration duration = asyncSnapshot.data;
        return Text(duration.toString());  
    }),
```

Wrap the `Widget` which you want to provide the current audio position in `StreamBuilder` and use the values received from `asyncSnapshot.data`.

For Custom Notification :

**Use `Audio` to customize Notification :**

```
final audio = Audio("/assets/audio/country.mp3", 
    metas: Metas(
            title:  "Country",
            artist: "Florent Champigny",
            album: "CountryAlbum",
            image: MetasImage.asset("assets/images/country.jpg"), //can be MetasImage.network
          ),
   );
```

and pass it to `assetsAudioPlayer.open(audio, showNotification: true);`

Comment: Thanks shubam its working. can you please tell one more thing how can i add image in notifiaction bar of this plugin player ? Thanks again

Comment: Edited my answer. @UmaizKhan What about the bounty ?

Comment: yes its yours right now it have 6 hours remaining to give bounty

Answer (score 1):

Use [Assets Audio Player](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player) package on pub dev instead.

It provides notification controls without any additional implementation.

[image]

An alternative plugin is [Audio Player](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayer).

Comment: mean just need to add plugin not any implementation in code ?

Comment: yes just use this plugin it and pass the boolean field when you play to create a notification.

Comment: but i use just audio so when the player open and'll run this so it will obviously make 2 sounds ? is it not possibe player will run on just_audio just I can use this plugin for notification bar ?

Comment: you don't need to use just_audio

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to take a look at this article: https://itnext.io/create-an-awesome-background-running-music-player-like-amazon-music-in-flutter-341a59efa936

It has an example about how to combine both packages.

Comment: This article is outdated.

Comment: Weird. It is from Jun 23, 2020. I'll give it a try, as I need to build an app also using those two packages.

Comment: The packages have changed the a lot in the past year. The names of the classes have also changed and don't match. I recently added an audio player in my app. I ended my using only audio_players package with audio_cache for loading files..